# Failed prop type: The prop `children` is not supported. Please remove it

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, children

I'm using Material UI tabs for the first time in my project, everything works fine but there is one error in console while running the project
[here is what i get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHH0j.png)
[and here is an example of the code where I use Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iVaJ.png)
Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please add your code snippet and logs as text instead of screenshot

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use prop name as 'children' whichi impossible because it is used as the inner components of the component u use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `Tab` must be a self closing element, that's why it is throwing warning because you used it to pass your `h4`, you should use props rather than pass explicit child to these components.

Answer (score 0):

The same applies for the [Bottom Navigation Action](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/bottom-navigation-action/) component from the same library, here is an example of Piyusha Rana accepted answer.

```
<BottomNavigationAction label={
    <Typography variant="h4" component="h4">
        Foo Bar
    </Typography> }>
</BottomNavigationAction>
```